# show the problem of find two subsets such that the difference of them of two sets is smaller than a value, is NP-Hard

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory, np-complete

As input, given two finite sets of integers X = {x1,...,xm},Y = {y1,...,yn} ⊆ Z, and a non-negative integer v ≥ 0. The goal is to decide if there are non-empty subsets S ⊆ [m] and T ⊆ [n] such that

|[image]

How to show this problem is NP-Complete? I'm quite confused

Comment: You might want to post this here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where did you get stuck? Do you know how to prove NP-hardness generally?

Comment: @ADdV Yes,  generally we do reduction from other known NP-Hard problems, but so far I haven't found an appropriate one.

Comment: Try [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: @ADdV I put sets X,Y into one set say S, and transfrom the problem to  many subset sum problems. Let the subsum be -v ..... v.   Will this not be efficient?

Comment: You're going at it the wrong way. To show NP-hardness of this problem, you have to show that you can turn an instance of Subset Sum into an instance of your problem. Indeed, it is more difficult—though theoretically possible—to turn this problem into subset sum, but this is not needed.